# Crystal reports 2008 Mod / Remainder on decimal numbers

Tags: numbers, decimal, modulo

I did a lot of searching around on this but still have not been lucky enough.

I understand that by default MOD / REMAINDER functions in Crystal Reports is meant for Integers.

What is the way out to get the remainder of dividing a Decimal number with an integer?

Example: 2.454 mod 1, I would have to get 0.454 as the remainder.

The rounding is set to .00001 for the result.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 5):

In mod operator ex. *(x mod y)*, if x and/or y is fractional then it is rounded before modulo operation is taken.

use `Remainder(num, denom)` function

see help on Remainder Function